# Swift error handling, what are the errors though?

Tags: error-handling, swift2

Each guide I find on swift 2.0 error handling shows handling errors on a custom class. I know how to do, try, catch but what I don't know is what to catch. I know I'm testing for certain enum to indicate the error but where or how do i find these error enums if i did not create the class?

Im using

```
 class func JSONObjectWithData(_ data: NSData,
                      options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions) throws -> AnyObject
```

so it says it throws and I would like to handle that but what does it throw? how do I know what enums to catch in the catch block? No doubt I'm missing something obvious but you know what it's like when you just can't spot it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For methods in the Apple frameworks look into the documentation and compare the method signature with its Objective-C equivalent.

In this specific case the Objective-C equivalent is

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data
             options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt
               error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

so the object in the `catch` statement is an `NSError` object

```
do {
  let jsonData = try JSONObjectWithData(someData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions())
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And, if you guaranty it should returns object then you could use below code:

```
let jsonDataObject = try! JSONObjectWithData(someData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions())
```

Here, advantage is we can avoid to use "*do { }*" scope of syntax